# Can matplotlib commands shift the coordinates of a plot (raster image)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, raster, qgis, subplot

I have some code that eventually produces a contourf plot at a certain location (lat/lon), like below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jJyp.png]

The purple in the image represents the matplotlib plot, which is then overlain on a vector world shapefile. Here, it can be seen that the plot is shifted to the left and up of the location on the vector (blue background). The center location on the vector is the red 'X' and the same coordinates on the matplotlib plot is the red '+'. I first thought this shift was coming from some PyQGIS code, but now I think its the matplotlib commands I have in my Python code.

The commands that I use to create the plot and then save the plot to become a .png image are below:

```
plt.contourf(Xa,Ya,Result)
plt.grid(color='w')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0,bottom=0,right=1,top=1,wspace=0,hspace=0)
filename="Results/submerged.png"
plt.savefig(filename, dpi=599, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w', orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None, transparent=False)
```

Where Xa and Ya are the grid coordinates and Result is the result that is plotted.

I then take the saved .png file and overlay it on the vector in PyQGIS. I asked a question on stackexchange about the shifted result [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318296/pyqgis-raster-image-shifted-from-vector-shapefile), but haven't gotten any responses.

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: I think in both questions the information and code is not complete such that people cannot help.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added the code that uploads and shows the vector shapefile layer as well. I'm not sure what else is needed since I have defined how I create the plot and save it as a .png file and then included the code that uploads the .png file onto the vector shapefile.

Comment: In my attached question in StackExchange I included the .png image and the vector shapefile if anyone would like to access it.